# Xamarin Forms 3 - what is the minimum version of the android supported?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to run my app(Xamarin Forms 3.1) on the device with Android 4.1.
The requirements(official documentation) are written:

```
"Android 4.0.3 (API 15) or higher".
```

But XF 3.1 does not work on versions lower than 4.4. I get this error:

```
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load monodroid: findLibrary returned null
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:34)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:22)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-13 18:05:37.752 E/AndroidRuntime(10979): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the minimum version of the android for XF 3.0? Which version of Xamarin Forms supports android 4.1?

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65172/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-monodroid-from-loader-dalvik-system-pathclassloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Forms 3 supported Android 4.1. My problem was in the emulator. the device is working.